# Problem in cloud carousel

Tags: jquery

All,

Im very new to jquery and am wanting to incorporate 'Cloud Carousel' plugin in another jquery plugin (jquery popup with grayed out background). However, I am struggling to make it work.

whereas normally the 'Cloud Carousel' displays as you seen on their website, in my implementation, all the images are sitting on top of each other, as if, they are sitting in a stack and one by one they appear on top. Any guidance for a newbie please?

Best,
here is the code Below

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="facebox.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/example.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cloud-carousel.1.0.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cloud-carousel.1.0.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
        loadingImage : 'images/loading.gif',
        closeImage   : 'images/close.png'
      })
      $("#carousel1").CloudCarousel(
        {
                        xPos: 170,
            yPos: 40,
            buttonLeft: $("#left"),
            buttonRight: $("#right"),
            altBox: $("#alt-text"),
            titleBox: $("#title-text")
        }
    );

    })
  </script>

  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="example">
          <p> <a href="#info" rel="facebox">Templates</a> </p>
      </div> 

<div id="info" style="display:none;">
    <div id = "carousel1" style="width:400px; height:200px;position: relative;overflow:scroll;">
            <img class = "cloudcarousel" src="button_images/1.png" alt="Flag 1 Description" title="Flag 1 Title" width="100px" height="100px" />
            <img class = "cloudcarousel" src="button_images/10.png" alt="Flag 2 Description" title="Flag 2 Title" width="100px" height="100px"/>
            <img class = "cloudcarousel" src="button_images/11.png" alt="Flag 3 Description" title="Flag 3 Title" width="100px" height="100px"/>
            <img class = "cloudcarousel" src="button_images/14.png" alt="Flag 4 Description" title="Flag 5 Title" width="100px" height="100px"/>
            <img class = "cloudcarousel" src="button_images/18.png" alt="Flag 4 Description" title="Flag 5 Title" width="100px" height="100px"/>
            <img class = "cloudcarousel" src="button_images/19.png" alt="Flag 4 Description" title="Flag 5 Title" width="100px" height="100px"/>
            <img class = "cloudcarousel" src="button_images/2.png" alt="Flag 4 Description" title="Flag 5 Title" width="100px" height="100px"/>
            <img class = "cloudcarousel" src="button_images/20.png" alt="Flag 4 Description" title="Flag 5 Title" width="100px" height="100px"/>
            <img class = "cloudcarousel" src="button_images/21.png" alt="Flag 4 Description" title="Flag 5 Title" width="100px" height="100px"/>
            <img class = "cloudcarousel" src="button_images/4.png" alt="Flag 4 Description" title="Flag 5 Title" width="100px" height="100px"/>
            <img class = "cloudcarousel" src="button_images/5.png" alt="Flag 4 Description" title="Flag 5 Title" width="100px" height="100px"/>
            <img class = "cloudcarousel" src="button_images/6.png" alt="Flag 4 Description" title="Flag 5 Title" width="100px" height="100px"/>
            <img class = "cloudcarousel" src="button_images/7.png" alt="Flag 4 Description" title="Flag 5 Title" width="100px" height="100px"/>
            <img class = "cloudcarousel" src="button_images/8.png" alt="Flag 4 Description" title="Flag 5 Title" width="100px" height="100px"/>
            <button id="left"> Left</button>
            <button id="right" onclick="alert('right')">Right</button>
      </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks all stacked until you call the cloudCarousel function with the appropriate selector. You need to call the function once the doc is ready.
Here's an example

```
  jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#carousel1").CloudCarousel({
      xPos: 300,
      yPos: 60,
      buttonLeft: jQuery("#left-but"),
      buttonRight: jQuery("#right-but")
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thnxs Federico, i have implemented your idea,it worked but now my functionality is not working, i have uploaded the code, kindly help me out, Shall be very thankful to u..

Answer (score 0):

Federico Zuppa clearly provided the answer Zain was looking for, however my comment is so closely related that I'm adding it in here:

**During page load the images are displayed in a vertical stack until CloudCarousel loads up.**

You can (harmlessly) prevent this by using css to hide the images.  Then display them as follows:

```
$("#carousel1").CloudCarousel({ ... });
$('#carousel1 ... img').delay(1000).fadeIn(600);
```

The delay is necessary because CloudCarousel takes some time to reposition the images - just because your .fadeIn() comes after your .CloudCarousel() does not mean it will work.  Your images still load up aligned left then rearrange themselves on the screen.

The fadeIn is necessary because .delay does not work with jquery functions that do not queue up items (see http://api.jquery.com/delay/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" />
<title>The Planets - Cloud Carousel Arbitrary HTML Demo</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="cloud-carousel.1.0.5-x.js"> 
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mousewheel.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
 <div id="contents">       
  <div id="homecontents">
    <div id = "carousel1">            
        <!-- All elements with class of "cloudcarousel" will be turned into carousel  
           items -->
        <!-- You can place arbitrary html inside these elements - although each should 
           contain at least one image tag -->
     <div class = "cloudcarousel" />
      <img  src="images/image1.jpeg" alt="GarField Cartoon Cat" title="GarField Cat" 
      />
      <div  class="caption lower center spacy" style="color:#00FFFF;">GarField Cartoon 
      Cat</div>
 </div>

     <div class = "cloudcarousel" />
      <img  src="images/image2.jpeg" alt="Mickey Mouse Cartoon" title="Mickey Mouse"  
      />
       <div  class="caption lower center spacy" style="color:#00FFFF;">Mickey Mouse 
       Cartoon</div>
 </div>

     <div class = "cloudcarousel" />
      <img  src="images/image3.jpeg" alt="Cute Bunny Cartoon" title="Cute Bunny" />
      <div  class="caption lower center spacy" style="color:#00FFFF;">Cute Bunny 
      Cartoon</div>
 </div>

     <div class = "cloudcarousel" />
      <img  src="images/image4.jpeg" alt="Bugs Bunny Cartoon" title="Bugs Bunny" />
      <div  class="caption lower center spacy" style="color:#00FFFF;">Bugs Bunny 
      Cartoon</div>
 </div>

     <div class = "cloudcarousel" />
      <img  src="images/image5.jpeg" alt="Calven and Hobbes Cartoon" title="Calven and 
      Hobbes" />
      <div  class="caption lower center spacy" style="color:#00FFFF;">Calven and Hobbes 
      Cartoon</div>
 </div>

     <div class = "cloudcarousel" />
      <img  src="images/image6.jpeg" alt="Winnie The Pooh Cartoon" title="Winnie the 
      Pooh" />
      <div  class="caption lower left spacy" style="color:#00FFFF;">Winnie The Pooh 
      Cartoon</div>
 </div>

     <div class = "cloudcarousel" />
      <img  src="images/image7.jpeg" alt="Little Chick Cartoon" title="Little Chick" />
      <div  class="caption lower center spacy" style="color:#00FFFF;">Little Chick 
      Cartoon</div>
 </div>

     <div class = "cloudcarousel"  />
      <img  src="images/image8.jpeg" alt="Mini Mouse Cartoon" title="Mini Mouse" />
      <div  class="caption lower center spacy" style="color:#00FFFF;">Mini Mouse 
      Cartoon</div>
 </div>
     </div>

 <div id="buttons1">
      <!-- Define left and right buttons. -->
        <input id="left-but"  type="button" value="Left" />
        <input id="right-but" type="button" value="Right" />
 </div>

 <div id="text1">
      <!-- Define elements to accept the alt and title text from the images. -->

       <p id="title-text"></p>
   <p id="alt-text"></p>
 </div>

 <!-- Initialize the carousels -->
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
    // This initialises carousels on the container elements specified, in this 
               case, carousel1.
       $("#carousel1").CloudCarousel(       
       {            
     xPos: 494,
     yPos: 100,
     yRadius: 120,
     buttonLeft: $("#left-but"),
     buttonRight: $("#right-but"),
     altBox: $("#alt-text"),
     titleBox: $("#title-text"),
     reflHeight: 65,
     reflGap: 4,
     reflOpacity: 0.5,
     FPS: 30,
     speed:0.2,
     minScale: 0.7,
     mouseWheel: true
       }
     );
         });
       </script>
     </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! While a code snippet could answer the question it's still great to add some addition information around, like explain, etc ..

Answer (score 0):

```
/*  style.css */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
display: block;
}
body {
line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
content: '';
content: none;
}
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}

/* end of reset css */

body {
background-color: #000000;
font-family: arial;
color: #eeeedd;
margin: 0px;
}
a {
color: #7799FF;
text-decoration: none;
}
h2 {
font-size: 18px;
}
#wrap {
background-color: #000000;
height: 550px;
}
#contents {
top: 30px;
position: relative;
}
#buttons1,#text1,#buttons2,#text2 {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```